# How do I fill an area with vertices lined up in a grid over a complex surface?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm looking for an add-on or a short cut to fill fast and symmetrically a *complex* surface that needs to be closed with vertices. Doing it manually it takes a lot of time. I tried to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and then *Grid fill*, but it didn't work. Neither <kbd>F</kbd> key works. Check the attached screenshots.

This is the surface that needs to be completed with vertices :

[image: 1]

This is what happens when I try to use the *Grid fill* tool :

[image: 2]

And this is what happens if I try to use the <kbd>F</kbd> key :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bridge egde loops and/or F2 addon can do the job here. But i dont think any tool can automatically do it all in "one click" for you here.

Bridge edge loops : select two opposite edges parts (with same accound of vertices in each) then ctrl+E and validate "bridge edge loops" :
[image]

F2 is an addon to easily make faces (mesh_f2.py). A tutorial and download link here :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImSNOuvkKsw

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/F2